# Excel advanced filter not showing results

Tags: excel, filter, criteria

Trying to put an advanced filter on an imported data list and copy to new sheet.

It only seems to either show everything in results or nothing except headers. I'm sure this is to do with my criteria, but I have tried every permutation I can think of (short of using VBA as I'm not competent with it), but nothing seems to yield actionable results.

If someone could have a look at the screenshots below and provide some direction I'd be most grateful.

---

[image: Sample data]

---

[image: Criteria]

---

The headers for the criteria are directly copied from the table headers and I've tried by separating the OR formulas into descending cells in the same column. Maybe it's to do with the syntax of the formulas I'm using, but I was informed by multiple sources online to have a formula that always returns a Boolean result and to have it tied to the first data in the worksheet that I want sorted (hence the B2, K2, O2, etc.).

Teylyn:

I was using this format for the criteria before, but it gave the same results - nothing at all!

[criteria 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIFSl.png)

Just tried again with the above criteria and no results again.

Additionally have tried with the following criteria - same again.

[criteria 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvbgm.png)

I need it to filter for every permutation of criteria columns 1, 2 & 3, hence the OR formulas being used before - I thought it might be filtering for AND all first row criteria, OR, AND all second row criteria.

I've even gone so far as to format all criteria such that it searches for first column (B2<=TODAY()-3) AND 2nd column AND 3rd column (O2="Not booked") then underneath, to imply OR, 1st column (B2<=TODAY()-3) AND 2nd column AND 3rd column (O2="Sent"). Setting out each permutation in this tiresome fashion. Still no results.

I can send you a dropbox link to the file if it will help.

Comment: Check that the data itself has no trailing spaces.

Comment: It's all determined by a formula - "Not booked" and "Sent" were inputted as written here then Ctrl + D to copy the formula down the whole way so nothing should be out of place there.

Formula itself is:
=IFS($B2="", "", AND($N2<TODAY(), $R2<>""), "Complete", $N2<TODAY(), "Awaiting Jobsheet", AND(OR($P2="Production", $P2="Purchasing"), $Q2=""), "Order Parts", $Q2>TODAY(), "Awaiting Parts", ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SE", $P2)), "Awaiting Production Date", AND($N2="", $S2="North"), "Sent", $N2="", "Not Booked", $N2>=TODAY(), "Scheduled")

Comment: You've lost me. Have you considered using Power Query instead of Advanced filter? Pull the list into Power Query, create columns with formulas that return flags like "keep" and then filter by these helper columns. Remove helper columns and load data into worksheet. Repeat when new data arrives by simply refreshing the query.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. Just some silly complicated formulas because I'm not entirely fluent with all the functions available on Excel. I'll have a look at Power Query or a different way around the problem. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Advanced filter correctly. It does not work with formulas like the ones you enter. You put one condition per cell, not a formula with OR().

Take a look at the documentation: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b#bkmk_5

or here:
https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-use-and-and-or-operators-with-excels-advanced-filter/

Comment: Have edited question to address. Please could you take another look if possible?

Many thanks for your help so far.